# Horizontally scroll all rows within column at the same time using one scrollbar

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

How can i horizontally scroll a listview within single column in a DataGrid, using a scrollbar that is external to the DataGrid, ensuring that each row scrolls at the same time?

(I would also like the starting position of the scrollbar to be all the way to the right, so that the last item in the listview is visible when the data is loaded)

I cannot use and third-party libraries or dlls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

***EDIT***

First column sample code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="325" Header="Header Text" >  
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TrendList}" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Background="Transparent" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            >
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Setter Property="resex:ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup" Value="Group1" />
                    <Setter Property="resex:ScrollSynchronizer.AlwaysScrollToEnd" Value="True" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Margin="2,2,2,2" Width="25" Height="25"  
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{Binding ArisingList.Count}"
                        FontWeight="Bold
                        >
                        <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <interact:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <interact:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenPCICommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ArisingList}" />
                            </interact:EventTrigger>
                        </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Label.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ArisingList.Count}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Label.Style>
                        <Label.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="pciID" Text="{Binding PciID, StringFormat='PCI Number : {0}'}" />
                        </Label.ToolTip>
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is what i have so far. The scrollbars are all linked internally but they arent linked to any external scrollbar

Comment: could you post a sample xaml? please explain `each row scrolls at the same time` as well.

Comment: the first column of the datagrid has alot of data that is too large to be viewed at once, so i want to make just that column scroll horizontally, but each row of the first column must scroll horizontally at the same time.

Comment: what type is the first column? do you have any template for the first column? If yes then do please post it too. I think we can achieve that.

Comment: I have added the code i am using for the first column

Comment: A few more question. Is the number of elements fixed in the list box of first column of every row? Are they all same size? If all of the scroll bar have different scroll length then how do you expect the master scroll bar to behave?

Comment: The number of listbox elements in the first column is not fixed, however it is the same for each row. 
Thanks for your interest so far.

Comment: Would you like scroll bars in all the rows move synchronised by moving any of the scroll bar? Or you want a new scroll bar? If yes then where you want to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a synchronous scroll behavior using Attached properties

may this help you achieve your goal in some way

for this I have made some changes to your template as well

- `ListBox` to `ItemsControl`
- `Wrapped` ItemsControl `in a ScrollViewer`
- Added `ScrollHelper.IsSyncScrollEnabled` & `ScrollHelper.ScrollValue` to `ScrollViewer`
- added a `Name` to main `DataGrid`

sample xaml

```
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="325"
                                    Header="Header Text">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      l:ScrollHelper.IsSyncScrollEnabled="true"
                                      l:ScrollHelper.ScrollValue="{Binding (l:ScrollHelper.ScrollValue),ElementName=dGrid,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrendList}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                   ... your item template here
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
             ... other columns etc
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

ScrollHelper class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class ScrollHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetIsSyncScrollEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSyncScrollEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsSyncScrollEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsSyncScrollEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSyncScrollEnabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSyncScrollEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSyncScrollEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSyncScrollEnabledChanged));

        private static void OnIsSyncScrollEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer sv = d as ScrollViewer;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                sv.ScrollChanged += sv_ScrollChanged;
            else
                sv.ScrollChanged -= sv_ScrollChanged;
        }

        static void sv_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HorizontalChange != 0)
            {
                ScrollViewer sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
                SetScrollValue(sv, sv.HorizontalOffset);
            }
        }

        public static double GetScrollValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(ScrollValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetScrollValue(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ScrollValueProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ScrollValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollValue", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollHelper), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnScrollValueChange));

        private static void OnScrollValueChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer sv = d as ScrollViewer;
            if (sv != null)
            {
                double offset = (double)e.NewValue;
                if (sv.HorizontalOffset != offset)
                    sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result is synchronous scrolling between all of the scrollviewers

[image: result]

**Extra**

if you do not want scroll bar to appear on all rows you can make use of triggers

eg

```
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="325"
                                    Header="Header Text">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      x:Name="scroll"
                                      l:ScrollHelper.IsSyncScrollEnabled="true"
                                      l:ScrollHelper.ScrollValue="{Binding (l:ScrollHelper.ScrollValue),ElementName=dGrid,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrendList}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                  ... your template here
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="scroll"
                                        Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                                        Value="auto" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

result is a single scroll bar scrolls all the rows data

[image: result]

**EDIT**

to get the default scroll position to show the last item in the itemscontrol, change the method `sv_ScrollChanged` as follows

```
    static void sv_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (e.HorizontalChange != 0)
        {
            SetScrollValue(sv, sv.HorizontalOffset);
        }
        if (e.ExtentWidthChange != 0)
        {
            SetScrollValue(sv, e.ExtentWidth);
        }
    }
```

Comment: pushpraj, that is brilliant, it is better than what i originally wanted. Originally i wanted a scroll bar external to the datagrid to control the scrolling, but displaying it on the row that the mouse is over is a better idea. Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: As a further challenge, any idea how i can get the default scroll position to show the last item in the itemscontrol? (I.e. the thumb starts all the way to the rights of the scrollbar track).

Comment: you can get the default scroll position to show the last item by changing a few lines in the code, see the `EDIT` in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to scroll across the `Width` of your `DataGrid`, but *not* using the `DataGrid ScrollBar`s. As long as there is nothing restricting the `Width` of the `DataGrid`, then you can do this easily with a `ScrollViewer`. Try this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: No, i want the datagrid to stay static, but the first column of the datagrid has alot of data that is too large to be viewed at once, so i want to make just that column scroll horizontally.